# Flask for loop returns correct records but no content

Tags: flask, mysql-python

The following Flask code returns correct number of records, including the corerct data in the terminal:

```
@app.route('/Contacts/', methods = ['GET'])
def contacts_overview():
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT contact.id, contact.title, contact.firstname, contact.lastname, contact.email, contact.mobile, contact.newsletter, bp.BP_name, country.Country_Name FROM tbl_contact contact LEFT JOIN tbl_business_partner bp ON contact.BP_id = bp.id LEFT JOIN settings_country country ON bp.BP_country = country.id")
    Contacts = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    print("Contacts:", Contacts)
    return render_template('contacts_overview.html', Contacts=Contacts)
```

The following For loop shows in the HTML page the corerct number of rows, but no contents at all:

```
{% for contact in Contacts %}
    <tr>
    <td>{{ contact.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ contact.BP_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ contact.title }}</td>
    <td>{{ contact.firstname }}</td>
    <td>{{ contact.lastname }}</td>
    <td>{{ contact.email }}</td>
    <td>{{ contact.mobile }}</td>
    <td>{{ contact.country_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ contact.newsletter }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Troubleshooting with this:

```
    <script>
    console.log("Number of contacts:", {{ Contacts|length }});
    console.log("Data passed to HTML:", {{ Contacts|tojson }});
    </script>
```

shows all the correct data as expected and as stored in the MySQL table. It simply does not appear in the table itself..

Comment: results are coming as tuples, to access each row's columns you should use `contact[0]`, `contact[1]` etc